# How to open one jsp from another through struts

Tags: jsp, struts

How to open **One jsp from another** through **Struts**?

For example,

> I have 2 JSPs, Page1.jsp & Page2.jsp.
>
> Page1.jsp **does not contain** any Form.
>
> Page2.jsp **contains a Form**.
>
> I need a link on **Page1.jsp** which **when clicked** takes me to **Page2.jsp**.

What are the **Actionmappings** needed to be **added** to **struts-config.xml**?

---

Update:

I tried adding these lines in **Page1.jsp**

> ```
> <html:link page="Page2.do">Page2</html:link>
>
> <a href="Page2.do">Page2</a>
> ```

In **struts-config.xml**, the following **Action-mapping**

> ```
> <action path="/Page2"
> parameter="Page2.jsp"
> type="org.apache.struts.actions.ForwardAction"/>
> ```

> The **"href"** one works, while the one with **"html:link" does not** take me to **Page2.jsp**.
>
> **Why is that?**

Comment: with struts version 1.x <html:link action="/action"> then in struts-config.xml  <action path="/action" forward="/pages/Page2.jsp"/>

Comment: Struts1.
Is there a difference in the way JSP pages are loaded - between struts 1 & Struts2?

Comment: only experienced struts 1, struts 2 look like a totally different beast

Answer (score 8, accepted):

with struts version 1.x ( in Page1.jsp ) :

```
<html:link action="/action">
```

then in struts-config.xml :

```
<action path="/action" forward="{path to }Page2.jsp"/>
```

Comment: You are welcome, too bad no one else bothered to give another answer