# cannot retrieve mapping for action error

Tags: struts

im using struts 1.2 and trying to create a link in jsp page with code

```
<html:link href="AdminModule/UserCreation.jsp" >
Create User </html:link> `
```

so that the link will move to page UserCreation in which the code like this is present

```
<html:form action="/adminUserCreation">
        AdminName : <html:text property="username"/><html:errors property="username"/><br/>
        Password : <html:password property="password"/><html:errors property="password"/><br/>
        <html:submit/>
    </html:form>
```

the struts-config file contain code like this

```
<form-beans>
<form-bean name="adminUserCreationForm" type="Admin.Form.AdminUserCreationForm" />
</form-beans>
<action-mappings>
<action
  attribute="adminUserCreationForm"
  input="/AdminModule/AdminHomePage.jsp"
  name="adminUserCreationForm"
  path="/adminUserCreation"
  scope="request"
  type="Admin.Action.AdminUserCreationAction"
  validate="false">
  <set-property property="cancellable" value="true" />
  <forward name="failure" path="/AdminModule/AdminErrorPage.jsp" />
  <forward name="success" path="/AdminSuccessPage.jsp" />
</action>
</action-mappings>
```

im getng exception

```
 An exception occurred processing JSP page /AdminModule/UserCreation.jsp at line 30


30:         <html:form action="/adminUserCreation">
31:             AdminName : <html:text property="username"/><html:errors   property="username"/><br/>
32:             Password : <html:password property="password"/><html:errors property="password"/><br/>
33:             <html:submit/>
```

root cause is

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: Cannot retrieve mapping for action /adminUserCreation
```

Comment: found this...this is simply doing what i required http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4015579/how-to-open-one-jsp-from-another-through-struts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[How to open one jsp from another through struts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4015579/how-to-open-one-jsp-from-another-through-struts)

This helped me to solve it..
Maybe it will be helpful for anyone else who has the same problem.