# Redirect jsp to another jsp (Struts1)

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, redirect, struts-1

This is the first time for me to work with Struts1. I want to redirect from a jsp to another jsp. For example: if the user not in session then redirect it to login.jsp; else go to menu.jsp.

I tried to make a tile: isLogged.jsp that contains:

```
<logic:present name="user">
    <jsp:forward page="menu.do"/>
</logic:present>
<logic:notPresent name="user">
    <jsp:forward page="login.do"/>
</logic:notPresent>
```

But it don´t redirect and the page is in blank (all empty in the code).

I do call the tile in all the pages of the site inside of the .

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hi, try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4015579/how-to-open-one-jsp-from-another-through-struts

Comment: I wanted to auto redirect when you go into the page. But thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several solutions <sup>**1**</sup>:

- #### *Using* ActionForwards

  If you have in your `struts-config.xml`:

  ```xml
  <action-mappings>
    <action path="/login" forward="/login.jsp"/>
    <action path="/menu" forward="/menu.jsp"/>
  </action-mappings>
  ```

  You can try (as in your code):

  ```jsp
  <logic:present name="user">
    <jsp:forward page="menu.do" />
  </logic:present>
  <logic:notPresent name="user">
    <jsp:forward page="login.do" />
  </logic:notPresent>
  ```
- #### *Using* the JSP's paths

  ```jsp
  <logic:present name="user">
    <jsp:forward page="/menu.jsp" />
  </logic:present>
  <logic:notPresent name="user">
    <jsp:forward page="/login.jsp" />
  </logic:notPresent>
  ```
- #### *Using* `logic:redirect`

  ```jsp
  <logic:present name="user">
    <logic:redirect page="/menu.jsp" />
  </logic:present>
  <logic:notPresent name="user">
    <logic:redirect page="/login.jsp" />
  </logic:notPresent>
  ```
- #### *Using* `global-forwards`

  If you have in your `struts-config.xml`:

  ```xml
  <global-forwards>
    <forward name="login" path="/login.jsp"/>
    <forward name="menu" path="/menu.jsp"/>
  </global-forwards>
  ```

  You can try:

  ```jsp
  <logic:present name="user">
    <logic:forward name="menu" />
  </logic:present>
  <logic:notPresent name="user">
    <logic:forward name="login" />
  </logic:notPresent>
  ```

---

*Notes*

1. The following examples assume that your files are in the root folder of your context (e.g. in the `WebContent` folder if you are using an standar eclipse project). If you have your files in another path, for example, in the `WEB-INF` folder, you should just change it to that.

Comment: Great! Thank you so much! I forgot to put the global-forwards. Though I couldn't work with the tiles, I just put the code inside the page that redirects and it worked perfectly. Thanks.

Comment: [Here](https://www.laliluna.de/articles/chronological.html) you can find more examples using Struts 1.x